Visualize an image pixel buffer with a bit depth of 3 i.e. each pixel having 3 bits of data
Question
What are the tools/standards/file formats by which I can visualize my image pixel buffer on which each pixel has 3 bits?
My Language is Go.
PNG header
Bit depth: 3 vs 4
An image pixel buffer is created on which each pixel has only 3 bits of data. Having saved it as a PNG file with header info of bit depth set to 3, I cannot visualize it:

But when the PNG file header info for bit depth is set to 4, I can be previewed, although I'm not sure if the preview is actually correct or wrong:

The change that I'm making is just the header info for bit depth, that's all. My code is in Golang:
    // Set bit depth and color type.

    e.tmp[8] = 3 // Preview is not possible.
    e.tmp[8] = 4 // Preview is possible.

    e.tmp[9] = ctGrayscale


PNG standard
According to Wikipedia we have:

The standard allows indexed color PNGs to have 1, 2, 4 or 8 bits per pixel; grayscale images with no alpha channel may have 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16 bits per pixel. Everything else uses a bit depth per channel of either 8 or 16.


Have you tried to pad the 3 bits into a minimum of 8 bits?

@ih8ie8 A 3-bit pixel buffer was created to reduce the image size as much as possible. Think of optimizing the memory usage for huge images of 8K, 10K, 16K, and 32K resolutions.

The PNG viewers specifically process 1,2,4 or 8 bpp because they divide nicely into a byte. How many distinct colours are in your image? A 4 bit buffer won't be all that much of a hit once the PNG encoding has processed it only the used codes will be encoded into the compressed output format. Or conversely could you get by with just  4 colours and 2bpp?

@MartinBrown Thanks. 3 bits are giving me 8 distinct colors. So, it is more than 4 colors of 2 bit depth and less than 16 colors of 4 bit depth.

Back in the days of Java 1.2 (we are now at Java 22), it required 8 bits per pixel even for a black & white image...  This wastefulness has been removed since then but I wasn't sure whether this influenced some image format standards. Apparently, according to @MartinBrown this is not the issue.

so... you're asking to be named image formats that don't have the 1/2/4/8/16-bit... "limitation" that PNG has? TIFF might do it. BMP might, IDK. in any case, compression removes all those worries. -- if you just wanted to visualize an image having pixel values 0 .. 7 (3 bits), you can use ANYTHING that can do a bit of arithmetic on the image, to stretch that to the usual 8 bits (0..255). python, numpy arrays, matplotlib, and you're done.

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks. Due to being very obsessive about memory usage, I don't want to stretch each 3-bit pixel to the usual 8 bits.

As you found out there is no such thing as a grayscale PNG with 3 bits per pixel. Maybe you are looking for a paletted image with 8 colors?

@Volker Thanks. Let me take a look at the paletted images...

How many colours do you need though? I suggest you try actually saving a sample file in the 4 bit mode and see how compressed it is. If the token space is only occupied from 0 through 7 then the encoder will take account of that when it does lossless compression. Likewise for any large regions of the same colour. ISTR all the bit reduced modes are palette based but there might be one that is nominal greyscale. If you really insist on having 3bpp then use GIF - that format supports it (but has considerably weaker compression so you may end up with a larger file).

@MartinBrown Oh, thanks. Let me check out the GIF...

you can be "very obsessive about memory usage" but then you have no room do do anything. you specifically asked about displaying such data. that necessarily requires decoding it. how do you think that's supposed to work without using some memory? I don't see this question being salvageable.


Having saved it as a PNG file with header info of bit depth set to 3

No, you did not. As you note yourself at the end of your question, there is no such thing. PNG supports 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16 bits per pixel. Whatever you saved is not a valid PNG file, and whatever you were using to view it rightfully rejected it.
You will need to use at least four bits per pixel with PNG. I am not aware of an image format that represents the uncompressed data as three bits per pixel. The uncompressed representation should not matter, as it is transient. Either you store it as compressed, where PNG compression will use approximately three bits per pixel in the compressed data anyway, if only eight values out of the 16 are used. Or you store it in memory as one byte, eight bits, per pixel, in order to deliver it to whatever will display it on the screen.
I just tried PNG compression with random 3-bit values in 4-bit pixels. The compressed data portion is 3.03 bits per pixel.


Have you tried to pad the 3 bits into a minimum of 8 bits?

Eventually, to test and visualize the correctness of the 3-bit pixel buffer, I followed the @ih8ie8 comment above.

// To visualize 3 bit depth, we pad the 3 bits into 8 bits.
// Then save as 8-bit gray PNG file.
func Pad3bitTo8bit(pix3bit []uint8) []uint8 {
    pix8bit := make([]uint8, 0, (len(pix3bit)<<3)/3)
    var color uint8
    var kolor uint8
    for i := 0; i < len(pix3bit); i++ {
        switch i % 3 {
        case 0:
            color = pix3bit[i] & 0b11100000
            color <<= 0
            pix8bit = append(pix8bit, color)
            color = pix3bit[i] & 0b00011100
            color <<= 3
            pix8bit = append(pix8bit, color)
            color = pix3bit[i] & 0b00000011
            kolor = pix3bit[i+1] & 0b10000000
            color = (color << 6) | (kolor >> 2)
            pix8bit = append(pix8bit, color)
        case 1:
            color = pix3bit[i] & 0b01110000
            color <<= 1
            pix8bit = append(pix8bit, color)
            color = pix3bit[i] & 0b00001110
            color <<= 4
            pix8bit = append(pix8bit, color)
            color = pix3bit[i] & 0b00000001
            kolor = pix3bit[i+1] & 0b11000000
            color = (color << 7) | (kolor >> 1)
            pix8bit = append(pix8bit, color)
        case 2:
            color = pix3bit[i] & 0b00111000
            color <<= 2
            pix8bit = append(pix8bit, color)
            color = pix3bit[i] & 0b00000111
            color <<= 5
            pix8bit = append(pix8bit, color)
        default:
            log.Fatalln("Code shouldn't reach here.")
        }
    }
    return pix8bit
}

This image might clarify the above procedure:

Then save as a gray 8-bit PNG file:
                // PNG specification doesn't recognize 3 bit depth at all.
                // To visualize 3 bit depth, we pad the 3 bits into 8 bits.
                pix8bit := Pad3bitTo8bit(*pix)

                // Save as 8-bit gray PNG file.
                img.SavePNG(tt.name+"-gray-3bit--padded-to-8bit.png", &image.Gray{
                    Pix:    pix8bit,
                    Rect:   rect,
                    Stride: 1 * rect.Dx(), // For 8-bit pixels.
                })

